# JAXB Unmarshalling performance improvement?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

So I have a project setup and am trying out JAXB parsing. I understand that Creation of context is what takes loads of time and so i have created a singleton instance and am using it whenever required. Since unmarshaller is not threadsafe I create it everytime I have to parse something.

My code for unmarshalling looks like this-

```
public static MyObj unmarshallThis(Node toParse) {
    Unmarshaller jUnmarsh = jaxbCntxt.createUnmarshaller();
    MyObj obj = (MyObj) jUnmarsh.unmarshall(toParse);
    return obj;
}
```

Code might have syntax errors, I have typed them over mobile, using the machine that I work on is not an option. :)

Now I had added code to calculate how much time this snippet of code takes. I noticed something odd, when I unmarshall the first XML it takes somehwere between 400-600 ms, but when I call the same method to unmarshall another different XML (same schema) it takes 30 ms or less, this happens until the JVM is restarted. The first unmarshall after JVM restart always takes 10x greater time and all subsequent unmarshalling takes 10x lesser times.

Now this gives me the illusion of a performance upgrade after the first unmarshall, but I would like to know what causes this performance boost? Does the unmarshall() method actually do something the first time and then reuse it for subsequent unmarshalls?

If I add a stock XML in the init() method or a constructor, along with JAXB context creation, then would my unmarshalls be faster? I am asking this because I would have to implement this in a WebApp and am looking for all possible ways to improve the performance.

Note: This is going to be a small part in an government app, so I cant change the input (using Node currently). But if there is a much better way of doing this then do let me know, I can take that up with management, hoping they somehow understand it. But right now I am just curious why 1st unmarshall takes time and the rest dont.

Comment: for one the first run is interpreted byte code that gets compiled the further runs are optimized compiled binary code(reusing previous values if detectable and possible). - I am talking about the runtime Jit compiler not the javac .

Comment: So if I have a stock xml and call the method once using it when initializing, then I would see an improvement in performance when actually using it in my webapp. Is this a correct statement?

Comment: I am not sure if I dont miss anything in the question. In general with Java if you execute code the first time it gets compiled to machine specific "binary code" (in oposite to machine independent "byte code") and further runs just use that compiled code(unless it gets "deoptimized" because some of the asumptions java made turn out to be wrong). Details are highly sophisticated.

Comment: Maybe additional: for example  java does inlining: it evaluates methods that get called once and after that just uses the  value(sure, only if detectable and possible). It replaces loops. It removes nullpointer checks. It removes if statements ....

Comment: A further noteworthy effect is filacces or in general IO. IO is usally quite expensive. Caches (and so called elevators) have a huge impact on performance. Improve and destroy peformance. Improve is fairly obvious. Performance loss happens often with misses which can be caused by reordering: for IO you have blocks and you try to create continous blocks. This is usally a good thing unless the blocks don't match what the next layer expects - in wich case another expensive reordering has to take place. But usually caches improve performance(its their purpose) .

Comment: I tried disabling JIT and AOT, it still performs better with them disabled. I am going to get this code deployed to an webapp and then see how it goes. Thanks for all the comments, I got a little busy.